# I get different values from the same array when I chose only one item

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

this is what I am doing:

```
 delta_list = [[ abs(daily_2016[y,1] - avg_max_array[y,1])] for y in day_of_years ]
delta = np.array(delta_list)
delta.shape # (366,)

print(delta)
```

and this is what I get:

```
[[5.23622047e+00]
 [1.64566929e+00]
 [7.54330709e+00]
 [8.05511811e+00]
 [7.81250000e+00]
 [1.06141732e+01]
...
```

when I print delta[1] I get [1.64566929] but when I print delta[5] I get [10.61417323]. This might be due to the fact that there is an e+01 at the end. The question is why are there these e+00/01 or even e-01?
If you need more information, let me know. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Scientific notation. ```1.06 e+01``` means multiply the part before the ```e``` by 10 raised to the power of the part after the e, in this case 10^1, or 10. Scientific notation is commonly used to write very large or small numbers without having to list a huge number of decimal places. It's also the default for displaying some types of variables

Comment: Just to be clear with what @DerekG is saying...`1.06141732e+01` and `10.61417323` are the same number, just printed in two different representations.  `+01` means "move the decimal one place to the right".

Comment: Thank you. I understood what it does now.